# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzrl

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-googleapiclient

I am developing an Android App which uses GoogleApiClient to get the user location.

During the development everything works fine. But after deployment some of the user getting this type of error. I think it is a Android Version 4.x.x specific issue.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzrl
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at com.acv2.activity.NearByFragment.buildGoogleApiClient(NearByFragment.java:520)
   at com.acv2.activity.NearByFragment.onCreateView(NearByFragment.java:208)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1078)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:677)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
   at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.onMeasure(SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:800)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:824)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:500)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2368)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2246)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1312)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1509)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I am getting exception at this line

```
  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(AppController.getmContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
```

Comment: Isn't this kind of exception you get when you deploy to emulators? App on emulator crash because it doesn't have Google Play services

Comment: I haven't tried on the emulator. I tested on the phone. Are you sure it is due to Google Play Services ?

Comment: No, i just remember seeing this kind of exception on emulators and this shouldn't be case with real users that download app from GooglePlay. What about this, working on 5.0+, but crashing on 4.x as you mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161671/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzmp

Comment: It is working fine in the emulator in all 4.x.x android versions. 
I have put the compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0' instead of compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' . and its working fine. Thank you for helped me out.