# App not running after adding firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, android-multidex

I've added **firebase-core** to my project for **analytics** but since then my app is not responding.

This is the class path for **gms** that I'm using :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

This is the dependency that I'm using for **firebase** :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
```

Also I've added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to bottom of my **build gradle** file.

And in my application class I'm just initializing the **FirebaseAnalytics** :

```
firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

And this is the error I got from the logcat :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.PHELAT.Vollip, PID: 15670
                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbdl.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbdl.zzaz(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcff.zzjD(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzchi.initialize(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcgk.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcgk.zzbj(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.PHELAT.Vollip.Vollip.onCreate(Vollip.java:84)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1025)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5548)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1576)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationError: com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzf
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbdl.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbdl.zzaz(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcff.zzjD(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzchi.initialize(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcgk.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcgk.zzbj(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6008)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5590)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5529)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1576) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
```

The error is pointing to line 84 of my application class which is the FirebaseAnalytics init.

Also, I did some research on this problem and I've found out that I need to enable **multidex** in my project, I've enabled multidexing but nothing changed.

Something that I've noticed is after adding firebase to my project, the apk size is reduced by 1mb and now I have two **.dex** classes in my apk, I think firebase is multidexing my app automatically but its not configured.

**EDIT** :

I'm switching back to fabric, I've just noticed that firebase is not working in Iran because of sanctions.

Comment: Look in your logcat at app startup for indications that MultiDex is correctly configured.  You should see a few messages that contains "MultiDex", like this one: `I/MultiDex: install`.

Comment: I believe this question has already been answered. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161671/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzmp

Answer (score 0):

use this version and try.

**(Note: use same version for all gms and firebase library)**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
```